# Make Emacs status bar draggable anywhere?

Tags: mouse, emacs

In Emacs, if I split the frame (`C-x 2`), each window has a status bar.  Historically, I could drag the status bar to resize them.

Unfortunately, with Emacs these days and just a few modes (for version control, line/col number, abbrevs, my programming language, etc.), pretty much the entire bar has remapped mouse-1 to something other than letting me drag the bar!

Is there any way to turn the status bar back into something I can drag, without losing all of my modes?

Answer (score 0):

You can still drag on the whitespace between status bar components, for example on the 2 spaces before the buffer name.

You can also resize windows with the keyboard: `C-x ^` (`enlarge-window`), the prefix argument is the number of lines to add.

**EDIT:**

Each mode line element may have a `local-map` property which is a keymap that applies when you click on that element. The mouse bindings for the standard mode line elements are defined in `bindings.el`. You can loop over the various keymaps you find in there; the key to remap is `[mode-line mouse-1]`. You may have to also deal with modes that add their own components to the mode line.

A mode line element that has a local keymap looks like this: `(:propertize ELEMENT ... local-map (keymap ...) ...)`. You can iterate over `mode-line-format` and detect and modify all such keymaps. It's more code than I care to write in this answer because elements can be symbols, which you have to follow, and lists, which you have to recurse into if their `car` is right. Unfortunately for you, when `:propertize` elements are nested, it looks like the deepest property applies, so you can't just override all `local-map` propertize by wrapping the whole mode line in a `propertize`. Again you'll have to deal with modes that add their own components separately.

Comment: Right, and I do use `C-x ^`, `C-x +`, etc., but sometimes the mouse is more convenient.  And if I'm visiting a version-controlled file from an untrusted mount point, the entire right half of the status bar is un-draggable.  I don't want to have to think about where to drag.  I just want it to work like Emacs 19 did.  :-)

Comment: @Ken: Emacs being Emacs, there is a way to do it. Unfortunately I don't see an *easy* way to do it.